# How to combine apispec and flask-swagger-ui to make a Swagger page?

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I can't find anything on the internet about how to actually extract and utilize the OpenAPI specification generated by the `apispec` package to make a Swagger page.

I don't want to rely on a package that hasn't been being actively maintained like `flask-apispec`. I want to use `flask-swagger-ui`, `apispec`, and other standard/well-maintained packages only.

Here is my test app. I don't know if the `APISpec` is working right because the documentation doesn't tell you anything about what you do with the object, but the Flask app is functional.

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from apispec import APISpec
from apispec.ext.marshmallow import MarshmallowPlugin
from apispec_webframeworks.flask import FlaskPlugin


app = Flask(__name__)


spec = APISpec(
    title="Doubler",
    version="1.0.0",
    openapi_version="3.0.2",
    plugins=[FlaskPlugin(), MarshmallowPlugin()],
              )


class InputSchema(Schema):
    useless_1 = fields.String(required=True, description='A string')
    useless_2 = fields.Int(missing=5, description='An integer')


class OutputSchema(Schema):
    doublyuseless_1 = fields.String(required=True)
    doublyuseless_2 = fields.Int(required=True)


inputschema = InputSchema()
outputschema = OutputSchema()


@app.route('/double', methods=['GET'])
def double():
    """A doubler.
    ---
    get:
      description: Double things
      parameters:
        schema:
          InputSchema
      responses:
        200:
          description: Double things
          content:
            application/json:
              schema: OutputSchema"""
    errors = inputschema.validate(request.args)
    if errors:
        abort(400, str(errors))
    return_dict = {}
    args = inputschema.load(request.args)
    return_dict['doublyuseless_1'] = args['useless_1']*2
    return_dict['doublyuseless_2'] = args['useless_2']*2
    return outputschema.dump(return_dict)


with app.test_request_context():
    spec.path(view=double)
```

UPDATE: with the following code, I now get a blank page at root with the Swagger title, but no content.

```
with app.test_request_context():
    spec.path(view=double)
    with open('swagger.json', 'w') as f:
        dict_ = yaml.load(StringIO(spec.to_yaml()), Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
        print(dict_)
        with open('swagger.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(dict_, f)
    SWAGGER_URL = '/'
    API_URL = 'swagger.json'


swaggerui_blueprint = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
    SWAGGER_URL,  # Swagger UI static files will be mapped to '{SWAGGER_URL}/dist/'
    API_URL,
    config={  # Swagger UI config overrides
        'app_name': "Doubler"
    },
    # oauth_config={  # OAuth config. See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#oauth2-configuration .
    #    'clientId': "your-client-id",
    #    'clientSecret': "your-client-secret-if-required",
    #    'realm': "your-realms",
    #    'appName': "your-app-name",
    #    'scopeSeparator': " ",
    #    'additionalQueryStringParams': {'test': "hello"}
    # }
)
```

Comment: For anyone who finds this in the future, I got flask-swagger-ui working by serving all the swagger files to a path and not using that, and definitely not '/', as my `SWAGGER_URL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my original problem was quite straightforward: `ApiSpec` has both a `to_dict` and a `to_yaml` method for exporting `swagger.json`. My second problem was more esoteric. I needed to use a `SWAGGER_URL` that was not `/`, because for some reason this caused the page to look for the core Swagger files at URLs like `http://swagger-ui.js`, which obviously didn't work. Once I changed my path to `/doc`, I still had a white screen, but that could be fixed by hosting the files myself at `/doc` (which I think `flask_swagger_ui` was supposed to do automatically, but hey, it worked).